# Entity Framework Core: private or protected navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

Is it somehow possible to define navigation properties in EFCore with private or protected access level to make this kind of code work:

```
class Model {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   virtual protected ICollection<ChildModel> childs { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: If it was private/protected, how would EF be able to know the property exists?

Comment: Somehow specify in modelbuilder. In some cases EF could have access to private fields. See https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/11/07/efcorefields/

Comment: Then, if you know how to do it, what's the question? Did you try it out? What happened? What benefit would it give you to have a private navigation property? Why even declare it at all?

Comment: Approach in this article describe regular fields, not navigation one

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two options, using type/string inside the model builder.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(c =>
    c.HasMany(typeof(Model), "childs")
        .WithOne("parent")
        .HasForeignKey("elementID");
);
```

Not 100% sure it works with private properties, but it should.

#### Update: Refactoring-safe version

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(c =>
    c.HasMany(typeof(Model), nameof(Model.childs)
        .WithOne(nameof(Child.parent))
        .HasForeignKey("id");
);
```

Or use a backing field.

```
var elementMetadata = Entity<Model>().Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Model.childs));
    elementMetadata.SetField("_childs");
    elementMetadata.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Alternatively try that with a property

```
var elementMetadata = Entity<Model>().Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Model.childs));
    elementMetadata.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
```

Be aware, as of EF Core 1.1, there is a catch: The metadata modification must be done last, after all other `.HasOne/.HasMany` configuration, otherwise it will override the metadata. See [Re-building relationships can cause annotations to be lost](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6674).

Comment: This is awesome. I wasn't able to test second variant, but seems like the first one works for me for protected navigation property, at least for inmemory database.

Comment: Hm... actually I'm already not sure it's working as I expect. The problem that I can't test this porperly, since EF autoload all entities already loaded to a given context. And in inmemory case it's looks like all data all the time loaded, so I a bit lost, how to verify this. I even create special question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44296548/1988021

Comment: It should work on the real provider too, as long as you a) eager load it with `.Include(nameof(Model.childs))` or `.Include("childs")` or `.Include("childs.grandchilds")` (the `.ThenInclude equivalent). You shouldn't use InMemory Provider anyways, except for unit tests, it's not meant to be used in production

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was able to check that. The only thing which worry me - is it possible to avoid using strings somehow? Since this could be broken on refactoring.

Comment: See my 2nd example above, you can use `nameof(Model.childs)`. It works even with private members, but only within `nameof(...)`.

Comment: For my case, I am not using lazy loading proxies, I need to set add `elementMetadata.SetIsEagerLoaded(true)`

Comment: Is there a way to use only a field for a navigation and not a property?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is possible, the whole model should be available and accessible at a low level with any restrictions on DTO's ViewModels etc

Comment: Not if you apply domain-driven design (DDD). Then restrictions are on the aggregate and its entities.